# Do these polynomials $x-1$, $ (x-1)^2$ and $(x-1)^3$ span $p_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I heard my Math prof say that if a set is linearly independent than it is known to automatically span the vector set.
I expanded the eqn and wrote in the form of 
$$x^3 (c_3 ) + x^2 (c_2 - 3c_3 ) + x (c_1-2c_2+3c_3 ) - (c_1 + c_3 ) = 0$$
For this equation to turn to zero $c_1 = c_2 = c_3$  must be zero.
So it should be linearly independent and thus span but the answer is quiet opposite
Thanks!

Comment: What is "p3"? Also please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: I'd like to suggest that your math prof perhaps did not say those exact words. You might want to ask in class whether your notes are in fact correct, because that statement is wrong. If you change it to "If, **in a $k$-dimensional space**, you have exactly $k$ independent vectors, then they also span," then it becomes true.  Similarly, if, in a $k$-dimensional space, you have exactly $k$ vectors that span, then they are also linearly independent. Both of those are useful theorems.

Comment: You need to be a little careful. $k$ linearly independent vectors in a vector space span a subspace of dimension $k$ over the ground field. I assume you are looking at polynomials of degree at most three over the real numbers (you see these how I specified both the vector space and the ground field - rational numbers would be an alternative). This is a vector space of dimension four, and therefore needs four linearly independent vectors to span the whole of it.

Answer (score 5):

The error is in thinking that $P_3$ is of dimension $3$. Actually it is of dimension $4$ so independence of these does not imply that they span $P_3$. All three polynomials vanish at $x=1$ so any linear combination of them also vanishes at $1$. Hence they cannot span $P_3$. Any polynomial which does not vanish at $1$ (e.g. $1,\,x$ etc) cannot be written as a linear combination of these three.

Answer (score 3):

Those polynomial does not span $P_3$ (set of polynomials of the degree $\leq 3$) since you can not express constant polynomials with them. Say you can, then for each constant $k$ there are numbers $a,b,c$ such that $$k = a(x-1)+b(x-1)^2+c(x-1)^3$$

so $$ k = cx^3+(-3c+b)x^2+(a-2b+c)x+(-a+b-c)$$

But then $c=0$ and since $-3c+b=0$ also $b=0$ and since $a-2b+c=0$ also $a=0$, so $k=-a+b-c=0$.

So only the constant $0$ can be expressed with those polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

To span $P_3$, any polynomial in $P_3$ must be a linear combination of the given polynomials:
$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=c_1(x-1)+c_2(x-1)^2+c_3(x-1)^3=\\
c_3x^3+(c_2-3c_3)x^2+(c_1-2c_2+3c_3)x+(-c_1+c_2-c_3) \Rightarrow \\
\begin{cases}a=c_3\\ b=c_2-3c_3 \\ c=c_1-2c_2+3c_3\\ d=-c_1+c_2-c_3\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}c_3=a\\ c_2=b+3a \\ c_1=c+2(b+3a)-3a\\ d=-c_1+c_2-c_3=-(a+b+c)\end{cases},$$
which is a contradiction as it misses the cases $d\ne -(a+b+c)$.